# Writing to file with php, function arguments

Tags: php, file

I have a problem with writing to a file with php. I have a random generator function (lottery system) and all I need is to change `round_id` after it generates one number.

```
    function getRandomNumber() {
        $fn = "roundID.txt";
        $file = fopen($fn, "r");
        $round_id = fread($file,filesize($fn));
        fclose($file);

        $server_seed = "39b7d32fcb743c244c569a56d6de4dc27577d6277d6cf155bdcba6d05befcb34";
        $lotto = "0422262831";
        $hash = hash("sha256",$server_seed."-".$lotto."-".$round_id);
        $roll = hexdec(substr($hash,0,8)) % 15;

        echo "$roll";
        setNewRound($round_id);
    }
```

In the 4 lines I am opening the file and reading it (there is only one number in the file). Next 4 lines, there is lottery system and in the last two lines I am calling a generated number and I would like to set new round (last round + 1). I used a function like this:

```
function setNewRound($current_round) {
        $fn = "roundID.txt";
        $file = fopen($fn, "w");
        $new_round = $current_round++;
        fwrite($file, $new_round);
        fclose($file);
    }
```

First function works really nicely but the second one completely doesn't want to work...

Comment: With `$new_round = $current_round++` the incrementation happens *after* the assignment. Use `++$current_round` or simply `$current_round+1`.

Comment: You may not have write permission on that file as well, not sure. Try @lafor 's suggestion first.

Comment: You could also use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for reading / writing files.

Comment: @lafor thank you very much.